# VSCode: code colors messed up after arrow function with implicit return

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have Prettier and Eslint configured for React and Prettier removes the parenthesis from around arrow-function implicit return statement. I'm fine with that, but as a result, the code following the arrow-function gets its
messed up.
Any ideas why the code turns mostly red after arrow-function within a class component?

[image: Before running Prettier]

[image: After running Prettier]

Switching it to this:

```
isWithinFilter = (filter, coords) => {
   if (coords.date < filter.startTime) return false;
   if (coords.date > filter.endTime) return false;
};
```

does fix the problem, but it isn't what I want to do.

Comment: What does `eslint` say the issue is when you mousehover over the red squiggly lines?

Comment: Eslint wants to remove the parenthesis from around that implicit return statement. After it does that, the colouring goes wrong.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that the problem lies with the '<=' operator. If I switch the second part of that return statement comparison around to use '>=' then colouring stats correct. I don't think this is an eslint problem. It's either in Vscode itself or the colouring theme I'm using. I have to try some other theme.

Comment: It might be an order of operations issue, where (I forget off the top of my head) maybe &amp;amp;&amp;amp; is the LAST thing that happens, so when you don&amp;#39;t have a parentheses (aka picture 2), JavaScript and its syntax highlighting freaks out. What happens if you do `(filter, coords) =&amp;gt; (filter.startTime &amp;lt;= coords.date) &amp;amp;&amp;amp; (coords.date &amp;lt;= filter.endTime)`? I&#39;m not at a computer right now and therefore cannot check, but this might fix your issue OR it might also be bad code where it&#39;s trying to do `(() => {}) && true`.

Comment: I found out that the problem is with 'Charcoal-Oceanic-Next' theme in VSCode. I posted an issue on github about it. Putting parenthesis around the statement would fix the coloring problem, but Eslint/Prettier want's to write the statement without parenthesis. And I like it also that way, so I think I'll try some other theme.